# replace space by - using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

hi i have this code in my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ single.php?title=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and i have spaces in the url and need to replace them with dash (-)

how can i do that;
this  is one of my pages to test

```
http://www.einfogarden.com/%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%8A%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B1%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L,NE]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# convert %20 to -
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [N,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ single.php?title=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: dear it steal not working i think there is something to do in single.php or in index.php

Comment: It has worked in my testing with the URL you supplied on your question.

Comment: for the same code i need to insert / (triling slash) in the end of url, how can i do this man

Comment: ok man its add the trailing salsh correctly but there is something happen i cant explan, check my site please einfogarden.com

Comment: I checked this website, didn't find anything wrong but since I don't understand language I probably didn't find any issue.

Comment: ok, when i put Adding a trailing slash every think is mixed and css stop working. otherwise every thing work perfect

Comment: ok for css issue just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: why i get more than one slash in every post i open after the first one

Comment: Can you tell me specific link?

Comment: http://einfogarden.com/%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%AD-%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9/////

Comment: When I clicked around on your website I just get: `http://einfogarden.com/%D9%88%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B7%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%8A%D8%AD-%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A9/` with a single trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the first rule with something like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:\ |\+)(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\ |\+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

So instead of just redirecting direct requests to the "/title", you first internally rewrite it to "/title" (first rule), then iteratively replace all spaces and "+"'s with dashes "-" (second rule). When there are no more spaces or "+"'s in the URI, redirect (third rule).

Then you'd need to edit your `single.php` so that it can interpret "title"'s with dashes instead of spaces.

Comment: how can i make single.php interpret "title"'s with dashes instead of spaces.

Comment: @Odayr You may need to edit the code in the `single.php` script. Look at how it interprets the `title` parameter.